# How should I search in a row based text file containing records to modify?

Tags: php, regex, search

My data is in a text file as follows:

```
ID: 12345
Name: Cem
Surname: Mehmet
Age: 19

ID: 22222
Name: Yasar
Surname: Gormez
Age: 25
```

...and so on.

I would like to search with ID and change other fields of the records such as age. How should I build up this record and modify?

```html
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
        <title>search</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <form method="POST"> 
            <input type="text" name="q" id="q"></input> 
            <button type="sumbit">ok</button> 
        </form> 

        <?php if($_POST){ 
            $file = 'search.txt'; 
            $find = $_POST['q']; 
            $contents = file_get_contents($file); 
            $pattern = preg_quote($find, '/'); 
            $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m"; 
            if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){ 
               echo implode("\n", $matches[0]); 
            } 
            else{ 
               echo "error"; 
            }} ?> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: What is your **problem** ?

Comment: Go to http://www.phpliveregex.com/ paste some parts of your txt file content to `Your search string(s)` Write the right regex into field which would help you on building the record Such as `ID:(.+?)...` . I'm not a php expert but most of regexs supports multiline. Thus you can match whole record one hit. good luck!

Comment: You should really consider using something like [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/) or an existing flat-file-backed data store for this. The odds of you corrupting your data are very high.